# .send(formData) Error "GET 404 .../upload.php (Not Found)"

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

i've found this code on a website for uploading files using javascript, but it doesn't seems to work. Could somebody help me with that please?

Index.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="uploads"></div>
                <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
                    Drop files fere to upload
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And js :

```
(function() {
    var dropzone = document.getElementById('dropzone');

    var displayUploads = function(data) {
        var uploads = document.getElementById('uploads'),
                anchor,
                x;
        for (x = 0; x < data.length; x = x + 1) {
            anchor = document.createElement('a');
            anchor.href = data[x].file;
            anchor.innerText = data[x].name;

            uploads.appendChild(anchor);
        }
    };

    var upload = function(files) {

        var formData = new FormData(),
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                x;
        for (x = 0; x < files.length; x = x + 1) {
            formData.append('file[]', files[x]);
        }

        xhr.onload = function() {
            var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            displayUploads(data);
        };

        xhr.open('post', 'upload.php');
        xhr.send(formData);

    };

    dropzone.ondrop = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.className = 'dropzone';
        upload(e.dataTransfer.files);
    };

    dropzone.ondragover = function() {
        this.className = 'dropzone dragover';
        return false;
    };

    dropzone.ondragleave = function() {
        this.className = 'dropzone';
        return false;
    };
}());
```

and upload.php :

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json");
$uploaded = array();
if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name'][0])){
    
    foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $position => $name){
        
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$position], 'uploads/'.$name)){
               $uploaded[] = array(
                   'name' => $name,
                   'file' => 'uploads/'.$name
               );                                                                                                                           
        }       
    }   
}
  echo json_encode($uploaded); 
  
  ?>
```

And now this issue :

> GET .../upload.php 404 (Not Found)

and related code to issue :

```
xhr.send(formData);
```

btw what is that "GET" showing in console??

Comment: The URL (porting?action=order) you send the request is not found

Comment: ^^^ You don't appear to have shown the code that's causing the problem, as the URL Teemu pointed out isn't in the code shown.

Comment: I am really thankful for the help, but something was wrong with my issue i edited my post, i am sorry.
Yes Teemu, as i updated my question i got that upload.php file can not be found, but why is that? the upload.php is exactly next to the other files. i can not believe i tried 8 different ways to setup file uploading but each one of them has common but unsolvable issues...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just saved the file "Upload.php" with uppercase "U" which should be "upload.php".

Comment: Saving a file with a typo? I believe it's fine for a beginner, middle, senior, and executive. Don't be so hard on yourself. :)

Comment: I'm really glad to hear that, but as you mentioned about pro guys, i didn't mean to disrespect anyone really.
Yeah i guess better not to be so hard on myself, Thank you.